# aws-sdk ruby and connection reset rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using aws-sdk gem with my rails app and paperclip to upload images to amazon s3 ..but I found these error always when I'm trying to upload images .

```
Errno::ECONNRESET (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.):
```

I searched a lot with no solution for that.I was using it correctly for more than 6 months and suddenly there error raised.I check the credentials and still raising these issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in my windows clock and time zone after fixing them to the right time and time zone ,,the problem gone